# Hamiltonian of wavefunction of $2s$ and $2p$ orbitals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, orbitals

I have recently developed an interest in the analysis of a certain problem in atomic chemistry regarding the energies of $4s$ and $3d$ orbitals, and I observed that even though the wavefunction of $2s$ is distinctly further from the nucleus at most points compared with $2p$, it is degenerate with it in a hydrogenic system.

This is apparently because of the fact that $2s$, unlike  $2p$, has a portion of electron density extremely close to the nucleus, as shown here. I am interested in a mathematical proof of this degeneracy given their respective wavefunctions, ideally one that clearly shows how the distance affects the total energy.

[image]

These wavefunctions of $2s$ and $2p$ (with $mℓ=0$) are described here, where the final row is the wavefunction and the former two are the principal. (clearer pic on pg5 of http://boron.physics.metu.edu.tr/ozdogan/ModernPhysics/chapter6.pdf)

[image]

I know that to find the energy would require taking a Hamiltonian of this wavefunction according to Schrodinger's equation, but I had approached this problem from a chemistry perspective, and am therefore unfamiliar with how to do so, especially regarding the coordinate system.

Can someone prove this degeneracy?

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian is not specific to these wavefunctions.  Rather these wavefunctions are solutions of a differential equation representing the Hamiltonian in operator form.  The Hamiltonian is just the standard [Hamiltonian for a hydrogen atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction):
$$
\hat H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 -\frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r}
$$
It is most conveniently solved in spherical coordinates, and the steps to solution found in pretty much any textbook.

Answer (score 1):

The Hamiltonian of the hydrogen atom, which is given in the pdf you linked, is
$$
\hat{H} = \frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^{2} - \frac{e^{2}}{r}
$$
where $m$ is the mass of the electron, $e$ the elementary charge, and $r$ the distance of the electron from the nucleus. By solving the Schrödinger equation is the same way that it is solved in your pdf, one obtains the energy as a function of only one quantum number $n$:
$$
E_{n} = \frac{\epsilon}{n^{2}}, \qquad n\in\mathbb{N}
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a constant and also obtains other two quantum numbers $l=0,1,2,\dots,n-1$ and $m=-l,-l+1,\dots,0,l-1,l$. However, the [*accidental degeneracy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_energy_levels#Accidental_degeneracy) in the hydrogen atom is a particular feature of the Coulomb potential in the Hamiltonian.

Therefore, for a given $n$, we have $g_{n}$ wavefunctions corresponding to the same energy $E_{n}$ such that there are $n$ possible values for $l$ and $2l+1$ possible values for $m$. Hence
$$
g_{n} = \sum_{l=0}^{n-1}(2l+1) = 2\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}l+\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}1 = n(n-1) + n = n^{2}
$$
This means that for each $n$ there are $n^{2}$ degenerate wavefunctions.

For instance, taking $n=2$, we have 4 wavefunctions ($2s,2p_{-1},2p_{0},2p_{1}$) in the hydrogen atom giving the same value of energy $E_{2} = \epsilon/4$. For $n=3$, there are 9 degenerate wavefunctions ($3s,3p_{-1},3p_{0},3p_{1},3d_{-2},3d_{-1},3d_{0},3d_{1},3d_{2}$), and so on.

It is important to note that this accidental degeneracy only holds for the hydrogen-like atoms since for many-electron atoms the effective potential in the Hamiltonian is no longer Coulombic.